# FFMPEG - Adding audio stream to existing MKV file (which includes an audio stream already) - Coming out squeaky

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to add an additional audio steam (MP3) to an existing MKV file which currently contains a video and single audio stream, such that the output will have the video, and two alternative audio streams.

This is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input2.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

This appears to work fine, but when I play the resulting output video, and select the new audio stream, it sounds all squeaky (bit like Mickey Mouse on steroids).

For the avoidance of doubt, the original (default) audio stream (and the video) still work fine in the output file.

The original MPV and MP3 files are almost exactly the same length (the audio stream is 3/100 (0.03) of a second longer than the original video) — I am figuring that is not the cause?

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Thanks,

Alan.

Edit:  Log file (Added 20200115 - 1745):

```
 # ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input2.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv

ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x55857e84b960] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[matroska,webm @ 0x55857e84b960] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 02:20:37.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15494 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 312.145000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 312.145000, end 640.640000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 640.640000, end 795.628000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 795.628000, end 1038.329000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1038.329000, end 1418.459000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1418.459000, end 1646.228000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1646.228000, end 1919.584000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 07
    Chapter #0:7: start 1919.584000, end 2279.861000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 08
    Chapter #0:8: start 2279.861000, end 2465.922000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 09
    Chapter #0:9: start 2465.922000, end 2827.658000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 2827.658000, end 3075.698000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 3075.698000, end 3253.083000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 3253.083000, end 3420.500000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 3420.500000, end 3620.450000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 3620.450000, end 3862.692000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 3862.692000, end 4150.813000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 4150.813000, end 4264.177000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 4264.177000, end 4433.220000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 4433.220000, end 4622.660000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Chapter #0:19: start 4622.660000, end 4955.159000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 20
    Chapter #0:20: start 4955.159000, end 5097.801000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 21
    Chapter #0:21: start 5097.801000, end 5339.042000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 22
    Chapter #0:22: start 5339.042000, end 5658.111000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 23
    Chapter #0:23: start 5658.111000, end 5821.024000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 24
    Chapter #0:24: start 5821.024000, end 5939.976000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 25
    Chapter #0:25: start 5939.976000, end 6349.260000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 26
    Chapter #0:26: start 6349.260000, end 6614.691000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 27
    Chapter #0:27: start 6614.691000, end 6928.922000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 28
    Chapter #0:28: start 6928.922000, end 7124.951000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 29
    Chapter #0:29: start 7124.951000, end 7397.181000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 30
    Chapter #0:30: start 7397.181000, end 7625.243000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 31
    Chapter #0:31: start 7625.243000, end 8004.205000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 32
    Chapter #0:32: start 8004.205000, end 8437.440000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 33
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 14020404
      BPS-eng         : 14020404
      DURATION-eng    : 02:20:37.429000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 202296
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 202296
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 14787020951
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 14787020951
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 02:20:37.428000000
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: truehd, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32 (24 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 1353728
      BPS-eng         : 1353728
      DURATION-eng    : 02:20:37.429000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 10124915
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 10124915
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 1427748260
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1427748260
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 02:20:37.428000000
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 7584
      BPS-eng         : 7584
      DURATION-eng    : 02:18:21.752000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 1870
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1870
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 7870766
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 7870766
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 02:20:32.174000000
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 12266
      BPS-eng         : 12266
      DURATION-eng    : 02:18:28.759000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 2556
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2556
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 12739742
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 12739742
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 02:20:32.174000000
Input #1, mp3, from 'input2.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 02:20:37.46, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.10
Output #0, matroska, to 'output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 312.145000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 312.145000, end 640.640000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 640.640000, end 795.628000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 795.628000, end 1038.329000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1038.329000, end 1418.459000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1418.459000, end 1646.228000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1646.228000, end 1919.584000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 07
    Chapter #0:7: start 1919.584000, end 2279.861000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 08
    Chapter #0:8: start 2279.861000, end 2465.922000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 09
    Chapter #0:9: start 2465.922000, end 2827.658000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 2827.658000, end 3075.698000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 3075.698000, end 3253.083000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 3253.083000, end 3420.500000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 3420.500000, end 3620.450000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 3620.450000, end 3862.692000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 3862.692000, end 4150.813000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 4150.813000, end 4264.177000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 4264.177000, end 4433.220000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 4433.220000, end 4622.660000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Chapter #0:19: start 4622.660000, end 4955.159000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 20
    Chapter #0:20: start 4955.159000, end 5097.801000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 21
    Chapter #0:21: start 5097.801000, end 5339.042000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 22
    Chapter #0:22: start 5339.042000, end 5658.111000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 23
    Chapter #0:23: start 5658.111000, end 5821.024000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 24
    Chapter #0:24: start 5821.024000, end 5939.976000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 25
    Chapter #0:25: start 5939.976000, end 6349.260000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 26
    Chapter #0:26: start 6349.260000, end 6614.691000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 27
    Chapter #0:27: start 6614.691000, end 6928.922000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 28
    Chapter #0:28: start 6928.922000, end 7124.951000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 29
    Chapter #0:29: start 7124.951000, end 7397.181000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 30
    Chapter #0:30: start 7397.181000, end 7625.243000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 31
    Chapter #0:31: start 7625.243000, end 8004.205000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 32
    Chapter #0:32: start 8004.205000, end 8437.440000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 33
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 14020404
      BPS-eng         : 14020404
      DURATION-eng    : 02:20:37.429000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 202296
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 202296
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 14787020951
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 14787020951
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 02:20:37.428000000
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: truehd ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s32 (24 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 1353728
      BPS-eng         : 1353728
      DURATION-eng    : 02:20:37.429000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 10124915
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 10124915
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 1427748260
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1427748260
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 02:20:37.428000000
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 7584
      BPS-eng         : 7584
      DURATION-eng    : 02:18:21.752000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 1870
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1870
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 7870766
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 7870766
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 02:20:32.174000000
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 12266
      BPS-eng         : 12266
      DURATION-eng    : 02:18:28.759000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 2556
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2556
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 12739742
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 12739742
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.4.0 ('Circles') 64bit built on Dec 12 2014 12:19:56
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-01-01 03:24:43
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 02:20:32.174000000
    Stream #0:4: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.10
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:4 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=12153.6kbits/s speed=15.7x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=14942.8kbits/s speed=9.25x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15239.4kbits/s speed=7.54x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=14992.4kbits/s speed=7.55x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15474.4kbits/s speed=7.13x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15580.3kbits/s speed=7.01x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15632.8kbits/s speed=6.98x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15709.1kbits/s speed= 6.9x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15599.5kbits/s speed=6.91x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15762.9kbits/s speed=6.82x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15724.3kbits/s speed=6.82x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=15615.7kbits/s speed=6.84x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15626.0kbits/s speed=6.83x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15550.4kbits/s speed=6.83x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15530.4kbits/s speed=6.82x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15632.8kbits/s speed=6.76x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15639.4kbits/s speed=6.73x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15771.6kbits/s speed=6.65x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15801.6kbits/s speed=6.63x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15799.3kbits/s speed=6.63x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15745.5kbits/s speed=6.64x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15784.7kbits/s speed=6.61x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15793.7kbits/s speed=6.61x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15865.5kbits/s speed=6.57x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15985.6kbits/s speed= 6.5x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15995.0kbits/s speed=6.49x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=16084.9kbits/s speed=6.44x    
[matroska @ 0x55857e89aba0] Starting new cluster due to timestampate=15632.1kbits/s speed=6.62x    
frame=202296 fps=159 q=-1.0 Lsize=16093151kB time=02:20:37.42 bitrate=15625.0kbits/s speed=6.62x    
video:14440450kB audio:1526121kB subtitle:56055kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.440162%
```

Comment: Share full log. Which player?

Comment: Hi Gyan - Do you mean the full output I get when I run the command in my OP?  If not, please advise which log.  Thanks,  Alan.

Comment: Full log from the `ffmpeg` command. What player(s) did you try?

Comment: Log added to question.  I only tried playing it with the default player in Ubuntu (Totem Movie Player) which is what I would (hope to) use to watch the video too:  [totem:
  Installed: 3.26.0-0ubuntu6.2
  Candidate: 3.26.0-0ubuntu6.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.26.0-0ubuntu6.2 500
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.26.0-0ubuntu6 500
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages]

Comment: Does another player show the same behavior? Try a more recent ffmpeg: either [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) the git master version or follow a guide to [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). Or use snap to install ffmpeg if you prefer but I am not sure what version it provides.

Comment: Hi - Windows 10 Pro default player has no problem, so it must be something to do with Totem on Ubuntu I guess.  Unless anyone has another view, I'll close this as not being anything to do with FFMPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try given different commands to copy the codecs?
You're trying to mix sources, with different codecs in each source.
Also, I will specify more precisely the video stream, if you stream is `0:0` I rather use that.
Something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input2.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mkv
```

It is not relevant if the length of the audio stream is different.

Comment: Hi Claudio,  To be honest, it has been over a year, and I cannot now recall what the file was that gave me the issues.  However, given that one player had no problem, and another did, is strongly suggestive that the issue is within the player, and not related to FFMPEG.  Thanks, Alan.